# Firebase ML Kit Face Contours : Cropping facial features

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I have the following code :

[image]

It creates a path along the face's outline and then I just crop it out. What I want however is to only get the facial features (Mouth, Nose, and Eyes) and not the whole face. How do I target these Contours only?

[image]

Comment: How about to use other [constants](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/face/FirebaseVisionFaceContour) instead of FirebaseVisionFaceContour.FACE ?